# How to custom size AVcapture

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I need to capture for my barcode But this my code capture is full screen. 
How to custom size or fix to small size.
please let my idea or code for custom size this thank you.

This my code capture is full screen.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol BarcodeDelegate {
    func barcodeReaded(barcode: String)
}


class barcodeCapViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var delegate: BarcodeDelegate?
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var code: String?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession();

        let videoCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {

            let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)

            if self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput) {
                self.captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
            } else {
                print("Could not add video input")
            }

            let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            if self.captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
                self.captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

                metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
                metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code]
            } else {
                print("Could not add metadata output")
            }

            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
            previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds
            self.view.layer .addSublayer(previewLayer)
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error while creating vide input device: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        for metadata in metadataObjects {
            let readableObject = metadata as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            let code = readableObject.stringValue
            if !code.isEmpty {
                self.captureSession.stopRunning()
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                self.delegate?.barcodeReaded(code)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I add CGRectMake(20, 40, 200, 50)
[show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti8Re.jpg)

Add CGRectMake(20, 40, 500, 100)
[show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppFXn.jpg)

I don'n know why width and height not add up follow code.

Answer (score 1):

Change the frame size of your `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`:

```
let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 50)    // something else!
```

If you're using autolayout, you probably don't want to deal with `CALayer` frames so you should create a `UIView` subclass, add your `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to that and set the layer's `frame` in `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.frame
}
```

Comment: When I add CGRectMake(10, 20, 100, 50) size of capture not change follow code. see my picture on post. thank you.